# При попытке создать базу данных, вылетает исключение, которое жалуется на строку подключения в App.config (Неизвестный раздел конфигурации)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

```
internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext() : base("DbConnectionString")//Здесь выкидывает исключение
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Library> Libraries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Books> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

Исключение указывает на строку `<add name="DbConnectionString" connectoinString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog= Knigi;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`
Пробовал использовать другие шаблоны - не помогло.

вот App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
    
    <add name="DbConnectionString" connectoinString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog= Knigi;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
         
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramwork">
          <parameters>
              <parameter value="mssqllocakdb"/>
          </parameters>
      </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: `add name` должно быть внутри раздела [connectionStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)